# How to pass a private 2d enum with array values to another class?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I have created a map variable that is a 2d enum(certain tiles with constant types), essentially I am trying to make it so I can render the map multiple ways without having to add the specific render methods into the map class, but into another class.

I have a simple console print command at the moment but when I use a nested loop to go through the coordinates I can't go through the array values(to print), but I can use the methods(getHeight(), getWidth etc. from the map class) since they are public, just not the array values since the map is private in the TiledMap class.

I've tried using the 'this' but I don't think I am using it properly, I don't understand how you can pass the map arrays with 'this', I have checked online for examples with 'this' but I can't find any solution to this yet. I assumed that since I passed a map to the render that I could access the array values as well but I can't.

Problem: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to TiledMap"

```
public class ConsoleRenderer implements MapRenderer{
@Override
public void render(TiledMap map) {

    //map = TiledMap(this); < attempt at using 'this'

        for (int row = 0; row < map.getWidth(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < map.getHeight(); col++) {

            System.out.print(map[col][row].asChar()); //Problem occurs<<<

            }           
           System.out.println(" ");
        }
}
```

}

```
Final class TiledMap implements ITiledMap{


private TerrainType[][] mMap;
private MapRenderer mRenderer;


    public TiledMap(int aWidth, int aHeight, TerrainType aType, ConsoleRenderer Renderer)
    {
        mMap = new TerrainType [aWidth][aHeight];

        for (int x=0; x<aWidth; x++) 
        {
            for (int y=0; y<aHeight; y++)
            {
                mMap[x][y] = aType;
            }
        }

        this.mMap = mMap;

        //sets the method of renderer
        setRenderer(Renderer);

    }
```

Any relevant material or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your variable `map` in `ConsonleRenderer#render()` is of type `TiledMap`. `TiledMap` is not an array type like `TerrainType[][]`. Are you confusing those two?

Comment: Yep, I was thinking they were the same thing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tiledMap class u don't have to use `this.mMap = mMap` because you haven't created a local variable in the constructor.You are just making mMap equal to itself.You are passing values to it in the for loop.You should use `this` only if u have a local variable with same name as the global variable.
And in your ConsoleRenderer class you are passing a class TiledMap not an array.You have to have a getter to acces your array `mMap`.But when you are passing TiledMap named map you use it as an array you can't just use it like an array, because it's just a class not an array of classes.
Make a getter function for you array mMap like this:

```
public TerrainType[][] getTerrainType(){
return mMap;
}
```

Then in the consoleRenderer you can do this:

```
map.getTerrainType[][]
```

Comment: Works now, no idea why I was thinking the array was being passed as well with no get method, cheers.